# How to use MySQL regexp with 'and' 'or' in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am using MySQL 5.x, and am trying to come out with a SQL statement to select rows base on the following datasets

```
ID | Type           | Name
1  | Silver         | Customer A
2  | Golden         | Customer B
3  | Silver, Golden | Customer C 
4  | Bronze, Silver | Customer D
```

I need to use regexp (Legacy system reasons) in the SQL statement, where I need to only select ID=1 and ID=4, which means I need "Silver", "Silver with Bronze" customer type, but not "Silver + Golden"

I am not very familiar with regular expressions, been trying with SQL like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customer_type` FROM `customers` WHERE 
`customer_type` regexp 
"(Silver.*)(^[Golden].*)"
```

Where I need to have the regular expressions in one place like above, but not like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customer_type` FROM `customers` WHERE 
`customer_type` regexp 
"(Silver.*)" 
AND NOT 
customer_type` regexp 
"(Golden.*)"
```

Although LIKE will work, but I can't use it for special reasons.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customer_type` FROM `customers` WHERE 
`customer_type` LIKE "%Silver%" 
AND NOT 
customer_type` LIKE "%Golden%"
```

I couldn't get the first SQL statement to work, and not sure even if that is possible.

Comment: If you are testing for the exact string 'Silver', why not just do `where customer_type = 'Silver'`?

Comment: try this , `"(Silver)(?!.*Golden]).*"` if the sql support negative lookahead.

Comment: shree.pat18 - edited my question to clarify further

Comment: Avinash Raj, thanks, but I get #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: @forestclown Should your output be only ID = 1 or ID = 1 and ID = 4? Are you trying to look for the condition 'equal in value or less than Silver' as your actual objective?

Comment: Use LIKE instead of REGEXP when the values are known (and exact), i.e "where Type like '%Silver%' and type not like '%Golden%¨'"

Comment: Shree.pat18, I need id 1 and 4

Comment: Jarlh I understand I can use like but for legacy system reasons I need it in regexp

Comment: Do you only 4 possible customer types?

Comment: tvelykyy - The customer types aren't fix to 4, and there is another old system adding new types from time to time.

Comment: I guess Avinash Raj describe the problem better, because MySQL not supporint negative lookahead in Regexp...

Answer (score 1):

Just try these one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id`, `customer_type` 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE `customer_type` regexp "^.*Silver$"
```

This matches "anything + Silver" or just Silver.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't take into account if we have Silver +?

Comment: Ok, then I didn't got what you want. So let us work on a "ruleset", than I'll rewrite the query.

So in my understanding there are the following rules:
Allowed: "Silver", "Anything, Silver", "Silver, Anything". Not Allowed: "Silver, Gold". Are there other possible matches/rules?

Comment: Almost there with the rules, but instead of Not allowed Silver, Gold, which should be Not allowed Gold.

Comment: Basically following the rules like [ SELECT DISTINCT `customer_type` FROM `customers` WHERE 
`customer_type` LIKE "%Silver%" 
AND NOT 
customer_type` LIKE "%Golden%" ] but done in one regexp

Comment: Not sure if it can be done in MySQL because MySQL doesn't support negative lookahead in Regexp

Comment: So you want every combination which includes "Silver" but doesn't contain "Golden"?